# Using arcpy.mapping.ExportToTIFF() to create dataframe geotiff

Tags: arcpy, geotiff-tiff, export

Has anyone created a dataframe geotiff using arcpy.mapping.ExportToTIFF() with satisfactory results?

My output has poor quality and the georeferencing is significantly off.
This example is the geotiff at 50% transparency on top of my data. The shift between "South El Monte" is the best shift example. 
[image]

Here is an example of the code:

```
currentMxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"F:\Test\amp_Edit.mxd")
dataFrame = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(currentMxd, "Layers")[0] 
arcpy.mapping.ExportToTIFF(currentMxd, r"F:\Test\outtif.tif", dataFrame, df_export_width = 46000, df_export_height = 29000, resolution = 1000, geoTIFF_tags = True)
```

Comment: I should also note that I am trying to create the dataframe geotiff from an MXD that is saved in Layout view.

Answer (score 2):

After further research I found a solution to my problem [here.](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4515/how-do-you-write-a-world-file-when-exporting-a-tiff-with-arcpy-mapping)

I was using an incorrect aspect ratio for my output image. After preserving the aspect ratio of my dataframe the output lined up perfect.