# Export map to geotiff?

Tags: python, arcgis-10.1, geotiff-tiff, export

I try to export my map (layout or data view doesn't really matter) to a georeferenced tiff-file (geotiff). However, this presumably easy task is proving rather difficult to accomplish.

I first tried the code from [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4515/how-do-you-write-a-world-file-when-exporting-a-tiff-with-arcpy-mapping):

```
import arcpy.mapping
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)
arcpy.mapping.ExportToTIFF(mxd,r"D:\out2.tif","PAGE_LAYOUT",640,480,96)
```

All is good, a tif file is exported. But for some reason doesn't it contain any coordinates.

Some further research revealed [this ArcGIS help page](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Exporting_to_Layout_GeoTIFF/0103000002m2000000/) with a very detailed workflow. But it refers to an option that is not available in my export window:

> 4, Choose Layout GeoTIFF (*.tif) from the Save as type drop-down list.

[image]

What am I missing here? Do I need another extension to create geotiffs?

Comment: Have you seen this question? http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/26412/using-arcpy-mapping-exporttotiff-to-create-dataframe-geotiff

Comment: Try export Data Frame object rather than Page Layout. Page layout is in page coordinates, this may do some confusion.

Comment: @Luke, I did see that question, but didn't notice the difference between layout and data view. Changing that did the trick (also thanks to @Tomek)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make a geotif, just tick the 'write world file' option at the bottom of the export window.  It writes a world file that includes the georeferencing info for your .tiff.

You can do the same for .jpg and .pdf files, for use in other software packages.