# Exporting multiple dataframes as images using ArcPy?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcpy, arcmap

I use this code to export a dataframe to png, and it works.

```
import arcpy
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]
ar = df.extent.height / df.extent.width
arcpy.mapping.ExportToPNG(mxd,r"C:\Users\Kakemphaton\Desktop\out.png",df,1024,1024*ar,96,True)
```

Code from: [Writing world file when exporting TIFF using ArcPy Mapping?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4515/writing-world-file-when-exporting-tiff-using-arcpy-mapping)

This code exports only the first dataframe and always the first. I can't export others and I have multiple dataframes in my mxd (example_1, example_2, example_3). How could I export example_2 and example_3? I tried to activate it for example_2, but it always exports example_1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List the dataframes, then iterate through them (untested):

```
import arcpy
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
dataframes = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)
for df in dataframes:
    ar = df.extent.height / df.extent.width
    arcpy.mapping.ExportToPNG(mxd, r"C:\Users\Kakemphaton\Desktop\" + df.name + ".png",df, 1024, 1024*ar, 96, True)
```

Comment: Hello,Thanks, but i encounter a Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 6, in <module>
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.1\arcpy\arcpy\utils.py", line 181, in fn_
    return fn(*args, **kw)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.1\arcpy\arcpy\mapping.py", line 1210, in ExportToPNG
    layout.exportToPNG(*args)
AttributeError: DataFrameObject: Error in executing ExportToPNG

Comment: There was an extra double quote in the ``ExportToPNG`` call. Fixed.

Comment: Too bad, now, i have : Parsing error SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal (line 6) , thanks

Comment: I think the last line being broken over two lines may have been confusing - try a copy/paste of the code again after the edit I just made to it.

Comment: It Works with 2 \ : doesn't work Desktop\" but Desktop\\" works, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I like to encourage the use of better string formatting and better ways to join paths. By getting rid of all those plus signs, etc., it will be less likely to encounter such errors - here is a much cleaner approach and it's much nicer to read:

```
import os    
os.path.join(r"C:\Users\Kakemphaton\Desktop", "{0}.png".format(df.name))
```